# C#/WPF: Dependency Property is not updating the bound Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dependencies

I'm trying to bind a Dependency Property from my UserControl to my MainViewModel.

This is how the DependencyProperty looks like:

```
    public static DependencyProperty ItemHasChangesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemHasChanges",
                                                                                  typeof(bool),
                                                                                  typeof(MyUserControl),
                                                                                  new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public bool ItemHasChanges
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ItemHasChangesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemHasChangesProperty, value); }
    }
```

My XAML:

```
  <local:MyUserControl ItemHasChanges="{Binding Path=Changes}" Grid.Row="4"   />
```

Now when debugging and checking the Set-Accessor of `bool Changes`, I see that it never gets accessed when I set in the UserControl `ItemHasChanges = true;`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it.. I had to change

```
<local:MyUserControl ItemHasChanges="{Binding Path=Changes}" Grid.Row="4"   />
```

to

```
<local:MyUserControl ItemHasChanges="{Binding Path=Changes, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Row="4"   />
```

Took me about 3h to figure it out.. haha :-)

Cheers

Comment: For reference to others who read this, in Universal Windows Apps, there is no `OneWayToSource` mode. Instead I used `OneWay`.

Comment: `TwoWay` also works, if you need bi-directional updating. That also wasted me around an hour, thinking my property wasn't having its value set.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting `ItemHasChanges` on the control directly (as in, not by updating the binding source)? If so, that will remove the binding.

Comment: No I'm binding the Source to the Control and depending on a Action, I change the Value of the Source..